# After updating form should redirect back to form itself or to the show page or back to the list?

Tags: usability, forms, design-process, redirect

I am developing an app that consists of the CRUD operations. Lets say I want to create, read, update and delete clients. I have a page that lists all of the clients, page that shows a particular client and a page that is the form which you can update the clients.

My question is, as soon as we finish Updating the client form, where should we redirect the user to? I am thinking of 3 options:

1. redirect back to the form itself with a save success message
2. redirect to the 'show particular' client page, with a save success message.
3. redirect to the list of clients with a save success message.

Not sure if I am thinking too much about this but I would like to hear other's thoughts.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to the client page.

That’s the place where the editors can *verify* that their edits were successful and as intended.

And, of course, show a link on the client page that leads to its edit page.